# Shell : How to do minus between number

Tags: bash, shell, numbers, echo

I want to subtract a list of values from a number.

**I tried:**

```
DATACOME=1013
DATAREF=1010
1020

var=$((DATACOME - DATAREF))
echo "$var"
3
```

It works just for the first value in `$DATAREF` and outputs `3` instead of:

```
echo "$var"
3
-7
```

Comment: Pick a different language; `bash` is not meant as a general-purpose programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward approach is to save the list of values as an array `dataref` and then iterate over it with a `for` loop:

```
datacome=1013
dataref=(1010 1020)

for num in "${dataref[@]}"; do
   echo $((datacome - num))
done
```

---

If you don't want to use arrays, you can store your values in a string separated by whitespace characters and use `awk`:

```
datacome=1013
dataref="1010 1020" 

awk -v num="$datacome" '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        print num-$i
    }
}' <<< "$dataref"
```

Or again with a `for` loop using word-splitting this time:

```
datacome=1013
dataref="1010
1020" 

for num in $dataref; do
   echo $((datacome - num))
done
```

---

Or when using a file to store your values:

```
#input_file:
#1010
#1020

datacome=1013

while read num; do
   echo $((datacome - num))
done < input_file
```

```
awk -v num="$datacome" '{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        print num-$i
    }
}' < input_file
```

---

**EDIT:** on @dawg's recommendation, this is one of many possible ways to do this with `bc`:

```
datacome=1013
dataref="1010 1020" 

for num in $dataref; do
   echo "$num-$datacome"
done | bc -l
```

There really are a lot of ways to do this. Also, please **do not** use uppercase variables as they could collide with environment and internal shell variables.

Comment: Great answer. You might mention `bc` as well but otherwise perfect.